# Some interior tiles don't render

Tags: mapserver, mapcache

I am rendering multipolygons of FEMA flood zones using mapserver / mapcache / openlayers.  The flood zones render correctly directly from mapserver, but at a few zoom levels interior tiles (by which I mean tiles inside the multipolygons which contain no edges) are rending grey.  The odd thing is that when I zoom in further they display correctly again.  I'm attaching links to config & an example of missing tiles.

- [mapcache.xml](https://pastebin.com/0tMVmN0h)
- [floodbroker.map](https://pastebin.com/Uy1pJt45)
- [image of missing tiles](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10rVBsFoEQKboMzup0YEzP0pi1dH5hVJh)

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar problem getting 500 responses for some tiles but mine was with a LINE layer that I was drawing labels on. Ended up being a clipping error and adding `PROCESSING "LABEL_NO_CLIP=True"` to the layer definition cured my ills. I would suggest clipping is the main culprit here and to check `tile_map_edge_buffer` and `tile_metatile_level`settings for possible issues.
Best I can tell my labels were drawing outside the tile boundaries and causing internal errors in mapserv.exe